# Gödel Universe and second law of thermodynamics

Tags: spacetime, time-travel

In the Gödel universe, which contains closed timelike curves and is a solution to Einstein’s G=T field equation, time travel is thought to be physically possible.

But as you need a spaceship (which expends fuel) to accelerate (as you are not on the geodesic), doesn’t this violate the second law of thermodynamics. Thus suggesting a potential flaw with the physical possibility of time travel.

Is there a solution to this whereby the second law of theremodyanmics is not applicable or is not violated?

Comment: With closed timelike curves, if you just sit still and wait a very long time, you eventually find yourself back at the beginning of your wait.  Note that the curve is closed, *only* if everything is identically the same at the beginning and end of that interval.

Comment: Thanks. But surely, a spaceship travelling on a closed timelike curve at spacetime point x in the Gödel universe has different physical properties than when it loops and travels back to the same spacetime point x. Hence, one could suggest that time travel is not possible since the second law of thermodynamics is violated. Or is there a solution to this/does the second law not apply here?